# Loading two arrays from a CSV

Tags: arrays, powershell, import-csv

I have a CSV File that has two columns Employee and Manager and I would like to import them into two Variables for use later in my script. However when I run my code it only captures the last data item in the CSV as the previous one is being over written.

```
$CSVFiles = Import-CSV "C:\T2\EmployeeManager.csv"

ForEach($CSVFile in $CSVFiles)
{
  $Employee = ($CSVFile.Employee); $Manager = ($CSVFile.Manager)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are overwriting the added data each time the loop runs. IN PowerShell the `+=` appends to an object. Try this -

```
$Employee = @()
$Manager = @()

$CSVFiles = Import-CSV "C:\T2\EmployeeManager.csv"

ForEach($CSVFile in $CSVFiles)
{
  $Employee += $CSVFile.Employee; $Manager += $CSVFile.Manager
}
```

Comment: That explains the OP's problem well and your solution works, but I suggest adding a performance warning re use of `+=` for "extending" an array iteratively in a loop.

Answer (score 6):

```
$Employee = $CSVFiles | Select -Expand Employee
$Manager  = $CSVFiles | Select -Expand Manager
```

Answer (score 2):

[Vivek Kumar Singh's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51287660/45375) explains the problem with your approach well and offers a solution.

Here's a simpler alternative (PSv3+), given that you're loading the entire CSV file into (custom objects) into memory anyway:

```sh
$CSV = Import-CSV "C:\T2\Employee.csv"

$Employees = $CSV.Employee  # collect the Employee column values across all input rows
$Managers  = $CSV.Manager   # ditto for Manager
```

This approach takes advantage of the PSv3+ [*member-access enumeration* feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375).

In PSv2, use [iRon's helpful solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51288013/45375).

---

Comparing the *performance* of the solutions:

- The member-enumeration solution in this answer is fastest,
- followed by iRon's `Select -Expand` solution
- with Vivek's `foreach` loop being the slowest by far, not least because use of  `+=` to (conceptually) extend an array requires *creating a new instance* behind the scenes in every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being my final coding to accomplish my end goal. I want to thank all the posters I used a little learning from all of you to come to the solution I wanted.

```
$EmployeeLists = @()
$ManagerLists = @()
$Employees = @()
$Managers = @()


$CSVFiles = Import-CSV "C:\T2\EmployeeManager.csv"

ForEach($CSVFile in $CSVFiles)
{
  $EmployeeLists += ($CSVFile.Employee)
}

ForEach($CSVFile in $CSVFiles)
{
  $ManagerLists += ($CSVFile.Manager)
}

$Employees += ForEach ($EmployeeList in $EmployeeLists) { Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter { DisplayName -like $EmployeeList } | Select SamAccountName -ExpandProperty SamAccountName }
$Managers += ForEach ($ManagerList in $ManagerLists) { Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter { DisplayName -like $ManagerList } | Select SamAccountName -ExpandProperty SamAccountName }


$EmployeeLists
"`n`n`n"
$Employees
```